# Tracking SignalR connection ids to see if they really exist

Tags: asp.net, real-time, signalr, signalr-hub

Currently, I am storing all connected user's connection ids inside my database by mapping them to actual application users. What I do is pretty simple here: I add the connection id to the database when `OnConnected` event is fired. Then, I remove that connection from the database when `OnDisconnected` event is fired.

However, at some cases (for example, when the process is terminated, etc.), I don't get the disconnect event. This makes my connection table unreliable because I cannot be sure if the user is connected on one or more clients. For example, here is a block of code on my `OnDisconnected` method:

```
HubConnection hubConnection = _hubConnectionRepository.GetAll()
    .FirstOrDefault(conn => conn.ConnectionId == connectionId);

if (hubConnection != null)
{
    _hubConnectionRepository.Delete(hubConnection);
    _hubConnectionRepository.Save();
}

if (!_hubConnectionRepository.GetAll().Any(conn => conn.UserId == user.Id))
{
    Clients.Others.userDisconnected(username);
}
```

As you see, I check if there is any other connections associated to that user just after I remove his/her current connection. Depending on the case, I broadcast a message to all connected clients.

What I want here is something like this: to be able to poll the SignalR system with an array of connection ids and get back the disconnected ones so that I can remove them from my connection list inside the database. As far as I remember from my conversation with David Fowler, this's not possible today but what's the preferred approach on such cases?

Answer (score 4):

This is just an idea.

On server:
Clients.All.ping()

On clients:
hub.client.ping = function() {
  hub.server.pingResponse();
}

On Server:
void pingResponse()
{
Context.ConnectionId; //update database
}

Comment: Hi, I'm just starting to use SignalR and want to do something that involves tracking. I like your idea on this one. Wondering if after more then 2 years this is still the right way or if there are simmilar solutions that might be more of today as solution.     anyone?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did:

I have a class **HubConnectionManager**:

```
public class HubConnectionManager
{
    static HubConnectionManager()
    {
        connections = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        users = new List<Login>();
    }

    #region Static Fields

    private static Dictionary<string, List<string>> connections;

    private static List<Login> users; 

    #endregion

    #region Public Properties

    public static Dictionary<string, List<string>> Connections
    {
        get
        {
            return connections;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods and Operators

    public static void AddConnection(Login login, string connectionId)
    {
        if (!connections.ContainsKey(login.LoginName))
        {
            connections.Add(login.LoginName, new List<string>());

            if (!users.Contains(login))
            {
                users.Add(login);
            }
        }

        // add with new connection id
        connections[login.LoginName].Add(connectionId);
    }

    public static bool IsOnline(string connectionId)
    {
        return connections.Any(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Value.FirstOrDefault(y => y == connectionId)));
    }

    public static void RemoveConnection(string user, string connectionId)
    {
        if (connections.ContainsKey(user))
        {
            connections[user].Remove(connectionId);

            if (connections[user].Count == 0)
            {
                connections.Remove(user);

                // remove user
                users.RemoveAll(x => x.LoginName == user);
            }
        }
    }

    public static int GetAllConnectionsCount()
    {
        return connections.Keys.Sum(user => connections[user].Count);
    }

    public static Login GetUser(string connectionId)
    {
        string userName = connections.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Any(y => y == connectionId)).Key;
        return users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LoginName == userName);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I'm using a dictionary that holds UserName and it's list of connections (this is because like you said sometimes OnDisconnected doesn't fire properly:

```
connections = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

Then in your hub, you can check if a connection is still "connected"/ valid:

```
public class TaskActionStatus : Hub
{
    public void SendMessage()
    {
                    if (HubConnectionManager.IsOnline(Context.ConnectionId))
                    {
                        this.Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).actionInit("test");
                    }
    }
    ...
 }
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, except that it should be thread-safe!

Comment: Good solution, but if your server was down and you saved connectionId in db/outer cache  and client was off, you will get "eternal" connection in your list :(